# Installing Windows 10 with Ubuntu in Legacy MBR mode

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I've a preinstalled Ubuntu - Dell laptop with 500 GB HDD.
Here's my partition table scheme:

[GParted View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YlX6.png)

I want to split /home and make a 60 GB partition and install Windows 10 in it, without damaging **any** Ubuntu data.

But, as /home is in logical partition, and Windows 10 is unable to install in a logical partition, what can I do now? Can I convert newly created 60 GB from /home, and make it primary? Will it affect Ubuntu system and data?

Also, when Windows 10 is installed in an empty HDD, it will create a 100/350/500 MB (based on Windows version) partition as 'System Reserved' at the beginning of disk. But, what will happen if I install Windows 10 in this case?

Step by step procedure to install Windows 10 easily in MBR mode, without damaging any of Ubuntu will be helpful.

Comment: Windows 10 will only create multiple partitions, if you install it on a GPT partitioned HDD, otherwise only 2 partiions will be created.  All versions of Windows support MBR, which is what you want, so don't boot the installation disk in UEFI mode.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about only the MBR mode, not UEFI. How can I install Windows 10 for the above scenario (without damaging any of Ubuntu data)?

Comment: Boot to the installation disk with legacy mode enabled

Comment: Yes, I know that. Did you check the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YlX6.png) I've shared in the post? I am able to only create a logical partition by shrinking /home, and I just wonder whether it is possible to have boot partition as logical, provided '/' acts as system and active.

Comment: You already have 3 partitions you will have to pick one to get rid of if you insist on using MBR partitions instead of GPT

Comment: Three partitions? Where? I have only one primary and a group of logical partitions. Can you elaborate your comment? I think you didn't get the question.